# javascript refresh prevents cgi execution

Tags: javascript, iframe, cgi, refresh

I am trying to refresh the page after a cgi execution. In my cgi, a tcp packet is sent to a port. it is called in a hidden iframe. Here is my javascript code:

```
function xx()
{

    iframe = document.getElementById('i');
    iframe.src = path+'?'+ac+'-'+type; // it is sth like that "a.cgi?11-1"

location.reload(true);
}
```

when i disable location.reload cgi works but if i enable it, cgi doesn't work, no packet is sent. I tried to put sleep between the execution and reload but it didn't work either.
Is there any other way to refresh the page after cgi execution?

Comment: The CGI script should handle the refresh operation. Using JavaScript to refresh a page can lead to unexpected behavior like this, so let the server side code handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up an `onload` handler for the `iframe` so that the `reload` won't trigger until the iframe has successfully loaded (which should mean your cgi has executed):

```
function xx() {

    iframe = document.getElementById('i');
    iframe.onload = function() {
        location.reload(true);
    }
    iframe.src = path+'?'+ac+'-'+type; // it is sth like that "a.cgi?11-1"
}
```

If you also want a time delay before the reload, you can do this:

```
function xx() {
    iframe = document.getElementById('i');
    iframe.onload = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {location.reload(true)}, 5000);
    }
    iframe.src = path+'?'+ac+'-'+type; // it is sth like that "a.cgi?11-1"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tested it. It works generally but sometimes refresh becomes faster than cgi. I get wrong results. I tried sleep before reload again but it didn't work.

Comment: @brknl - It is not possible for this reload to happen before the iframe has finished loading based on this code.  And, the iframe won't finish loading until the URL specified in .src is done loading which means your cgi has to be done.  I'm wondering if you have some code somewhere else that is causing the problem.

Comment: The cgi sends a packet to somewhere and it uses the packet and set some parameters. I try to get the these parameters again with refresh to understand my setting process is ok. May be iframe is loaded but this setting process is slower than that. So how can i make sleep or something else to wait a little or is there any other way you can suggest?

Comment: @brknl - Why doesn't your cgi just not return the data to the iframe until it's done with it's other stuff.  The iframe will wait until the cgi response is done and not be done loading until the cgi is done.  With the code I've recommended, I think you can fix it in your cgi.

Comment: @brknl - I added a second option with a time delay before the reload though I don't think that should be necessary if the cgi id coded to not return its requested data for the iframe until its other job is done.

Comment: its not just simple there are some midtiers between cgi and the process  so it can not send back any data. But i tried delay its quite better thank you!

Comment: but hidden iframe does not work at IE so it tried to make it with window.open like: if(/MSIE[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent) == true){myWindowHandle = window.open(path+'?'+ac+'-'+type); ..} same problem occurs here to but is there any other way like iframe.onload? window.onload didn't work.

Comment: @brknl - I have to wonder why you're using a frame at all.  If you just want to execute something on the server, why not just use an ajax call (works in all browsers) and since you don't care about the response from the server and its timing isn't meaningful, just set a `setTimeout()` for sometime after you send the ajax request to do the `reload()`.